# Full page height with fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css, height, wrapper

I am developing a site where I have a fixed header and a fixed footer. I am trying to get my content to be full page when there is not enough content and still be scrollable when there is.

What I have so far does this, but I am left with some extra space at the end of my page. How can I get rid of this extra space at the bottom?

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0yz9nx35/1/

As you can see in the fiddle there is still a scrollbar showing empty space at the bottom of my page

My code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.wrapper { min-height: 100%; height: 100%; padding-top: 60px; }
.header { position: fixed; top:0px; left:0px; height:60px; background-color: #333; width: 100%;}
.footer { position: fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; height:50px; background-color: #333; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `body {height:100%;}` add some padding bottom on `wrapper` to compensate for the fixed footer height. Here is the fixed fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0yz9nx35/9/

Comment: Thanks, really simple answer !! I just realized that I left the most important thing out of my question, which completely changes it ... So if you are willing to try help me (again) here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138210/full-page-height-fixed-header-and-footer-central-column

Answer (score 2):

You can use that on the wrapper class:

```
height: calc(100% - 60px)
```

Or maybe you could change the structure of your page by something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #global { height: 100vh; }
        #header { height: 60px; background-color: orange; }
        #content { height: calc(100% - (60px + 50px)); background-color: gray; }
        #footer { height: 50px; background-color: green;  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="global">
        <div id="header">
            Aenean
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            lacinia
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            quam
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `overflow-y: hidden;` do *remove* the scrollbar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any scroll bar to be on the `.content` block, you can try the following.

You can make `.content` fixed such that the top and bottom edges are below the header and above the footer respectively.

In this approach, you may not need the `.wrapper` block element unless you  need it for placing some background images, for example.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Content goes here<br>
    and<br>and<br>and<br>and<br>and<br>and<br>and<br>and<br>and<br>and<br>
    the end.
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```